# how to handle Untrusted Connection Error in selenium grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I am testing a web site which uses both http and https protocols depending on its configuration file.

I am writing my test cases in java.
My test cases are working fine for http but in https it generates a untrusted connection error.
I know i can avoid this using firefoxprofile manager but problem is that my test cases will be used on many machines to test this website and creating a profile on every machine is not possible
Is there any way to avoid getting this error so that my test cases works perfectly for both http and https.

Answer (score 0):

You could try invoking the browser with `-trustAllSSLCertificates` clause.
Here's a code snippet:

```
BrowserConfigurationOptions bco = new BrowserConfigurationOptions();
bco.setCommandLineFlags("-trustAllSSLCertificates");
bco.setCommandLineFlags("-disable-web-security");
bco.setCommandLineFlags("-avoidProxy");
settings.setReuseBrowserSessions(true);
settings.setSingleWindow(true);
SeleniumServer seleniumserver=new SeleniumServer(settings);
seleniumserver.boot();
seleniumserver.start();
```

Comment: thanks for the help but it is not working i m getting the same error after using your steps

Answer (score 0):

rs79's answer is a good start, but depending on your browser there are more steps you need to take.  I wrote up a pretty comprehensive article on testing SSL in Selenium that you may want to check out:

http://mogotest.com/blog/2010/04/13/how-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificates-in-selenium

Comment: my problem is that i m using selenium grid and my remote controls will run on different machines

Comment: Did you happen to read the article?  I run in precisely that sort of environment.  Selenium Grid is a detail that simply doesn't matter here.